# Dehumanising religions/cults

Tags: humans, religion

What real life examples of cults exists where people are turned willingly into work machines dedicated to one cause.
Where's the cause is strong enough to overwrite human emotions, natural cravings, morality and misery?

Most religions I know are based on either curiosity or fear, something that tries to give meaning to people...to give meaning to suffering and distress.

But is there an example which I can study of a religion which removes fear from the person, removes curiosity and any meaningful emotion. Something that truly turns flesh and spirits into tools.

Imagine working ants, they do not behave like individuals, they don't have an identity.
As far as I know, every human being is deeply attached to their avatar, their identity.... Their sexual, religious, political and moral identity.

Its hard to imagine a religion which snatches away all human identity.

"you are nothing, not a person, not a spirit, not a cog in a system.. You mean nothing and you were nothing before your birth and you are, you will still be nothing after your death"

Something like that?

If a religion like that does not exist, I imagine it could not be considered realistic in a fictional story, if not then... How would a cult like that exist and function to create a society like that of ants.

Comment: (1) In post-1950 English, unlike in other languages, the words [*cult*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cult) and *religion* have very different meanings. The word *religion* is neutral or positive; the word *cult* is derogatory. (2) At least (some forms of) Christianity and Mahommedanism do aim to remove fear from the hearts of the believers. (3) As for removing curiosity and meaningful emotion, have your never heard of monks and nuns? From a certain point of view, that's the entire purpose of monastic life. E.g., when a person takes monastic vows, they get a new name, erasing their former id.

Comment: [*Oboedientia perinde ac cadaver*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perinde_ac_cadaver) (link to French Wikipedia, sorry), "obedience in the manner of a corpse".

Comment: "*But is there an example which I can study of a religion which removes fear from the person, removes curiosity and any meaningful emotion.*"  [The Serpent and the Rainbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Serpent_and_the_Rainbow_(book)) is *supposedly* a true account of somebody turned into a mindless zombie slave for a voodoo priest. It's not *actually* real, as it was determined the author made it up, however it can be an inspiration.

Comment: You can't be nothing when you need to be something. On a ladder when deity is at the top evn if you are at the bottom you are there in relation to the top. Even if yo give human negative value it's still a value.

Comment: VTC:Needs Details. There is no organization (nor has there ever been) that entirely subdues human emotion, will, or identity. That's not even what "dehumanize" usually means. Even cults like the Jim Jones cult never successfully (if that was ever its intent) dehumanized anyone. Slavery may turn everyone into workers, and it may "dehumanize" in that it reduces the interpersonal value of the slave, but it by no means does what you're describing. There's a big difference between "treats you like less than human" and "you become something less than human." Which are you searching for?

Comment: ALL religions and cults are dehumanizing, to some extent. They all cause the onus of belief, of morality, and of responsibility to deflect from the individual to the Organization, the Belief. This is not necessarily a bad thing, as individuals can be very stupid without guidance. But the loss of freedom of choice IS there, for all religions and cults.

Comment: PcMan, I would disagree. I am highly religious, but that doesn't mean responsibility is somehow deflected from me to my Belief. Onus=obligation, I obligate myself to be a better human being because of my religion. There's no loss of agency either, because I CHOOSE to follow my religion's principles, I could drop my religion and just do whatever I want, but that would result in a net loss (negative effect) for me.

Comment: To me it sounds like you're trying to make [corporatism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporatism) go from an ideology to a very extreme cult, except suddenly everyone becomes a zombie. In a frame challenge: ants aren't the biological equivalent of some zombie, they're highly social animals which put the colony's interests above their own (), which sounds like a much smarter approach to a bunch of living organisms who are more than nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Well, while I don't think you could make someone act exactly like an ant, you could have a religion that acts similar to a collectivist ideology where an individual must work for the collective good. The ideology could be similar to the Marxist-Leninist socialist idea of the [New Soviet man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Soviet_man), the concept that a man or woman is willing to sacrifice themselves for the collective good. This idea was praised in a lot of Soviet literature of the time like that of Bertolt Brecht with his play/writing *Man Equals Man*. Also, make the 'dehumanizing' seem positive and treat it as self-sacrifice. In this religion, the person who lives a better life and/or is given the most by deities are those who sacrifice for the common good. Treat it less like 'you are nothing' and more like 'only as a group can you truly thrive and accomplish'. If you have enough people devoted to the religion, you can have those who seem too individualistic excommunicated or 'spiritually rehabilitated' until they learn to focus more on the group as a whole instead of themselves. I don't have any exact examples from a religion, but Marxist-Leninism's New Soviet man could be a good ideology to start from as well as other [political/social ideologies focused around the collective good](https://www.britannica.com/topic/collectivism), then focus on adding religious elements to these ideologies.

tl;dr: There probably isn't an ideology or human religion that causes people to fully accept they are worthless and simply work for the benefit of their community at the complete expense of their own life/happiness - at least not to the extreme described by the OP. However, there are collectivist ideologies that come close to this idea of giving yourself up to the majority and adding a religious spin to such belief systems could make a spiritual identity that does come close to what the OP is asking for.

Comment: While this is an interesting comment, it fails to answer the OP's question (and I'm not sure, if applied, it reaches the level of "dehumanization" the OP is looking for).

Comment: @JBH I know, but I think it kind of does in that my point is that this level of dehumanization in his question seems to be impossible by current means and there isn't a major religion/long lasting cult that has reach this level of treating everyone like they are worthless cogs working for the greater good. What I was trying to provide in the answer was the closest thing that exists in real-life to the collectivist ideal the OP is looking for that human beings have been willing to follow

Comment: OK, as a habit, you should start by answering the question "there is no such organization that I know of..." and then follow it up with your observation that might help the OP ("...but..."). Thanks for the edit in that regard. I've reversed my vote.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't (short of drugs or lobotomy) remove fear, curiousity, and other emotions from humans, because they're built into the biology.  The closest you can come is to get people to suppress them and not act on them.  Indeed, most religions I know of do just that.